# Confused about Javascript. A boolean function can act as a void function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to refresh some Javascript knowledge for an upcoming interview. I was reading [a blog](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-objects-in-detail/) that says

> "The delete operator returns true if the delete was successful."

and then shows an example of it in use:

```
var christmasList = {mike:"Book", jason:"sweater" }
​delete christmasList.mike; // deletes the mike property​
```

In that example it looks like `delete` is used in the manner that a `void` function (in the general programming sense -- I know that JS doesn't require declarations like `void`) would be.

Can someone explain to me, or give me a link to, the documentation that explains how `JS` functions can act with different return values, and does such require separate implementations for each return value?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: It's not really a function, it's an operator, and it returns whatever the specification says it should return

Comment: What do you mean by, "for each return value"?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the return value for the delete operator is always true.

Comment: @cyber_rookie: `var a = delete window.window; alert(a) //false`

Comment: The same way the `*` operator takes the two arguments to the left and right of it and returns their product and the `!` operator takes the argument to the right of it and returns its boolean inverse.

Comment: Its confusing @Cerbrus, because if you try to delete it from an object, it always returns true. http://jsfiddle.net/bL3224wv/

Comment: Because you're delteing delete-able properties.

Comment: it's still returning a boolean.  Even if `delete` were a function, it'd still be perfectly legal to simply discard a return value if you don't care about it, by simply not assigning it to a variable or otherwise inspecting it.

Comment: In general you never have to do anything with the return value of some expression. You can completely ignore it. The "callee" doesn't care what happens to the value it returns.

Comment: So would a statement like `delete myOb.myProp ? alert("deleted") : alert("not deleted")` make sense?

Comment: @SteveJobs: No, since that would also alert `deleted` if `myProp` didn't exist on `myOb` in the first place.

Comment: Ok, from what I can gather, you don't need to use `delete` as a boolean operator unless you care about whether the object was actually deleted, which you won't care about in most cases?

Comment: I feel like it is the exact opposite. In most cases you should care whether or not the object was successfully deleted. Stable, and reliable code will always check to make sure everything is working. That is because if the item wasn't deleted that may throw off certain assumptions that are made later in the code. I think what @FelixKling was trying to say is you never NEED to do anything with the return value of an expression.

Comment: @Adjit, correct. I was only talking how JS handles this. JS doesn't treat operations differently depending on whether you do something with the result or not. It's all the same. It doesn't care. That doesn't mean that there are not best practices around code design, they might just not be backed into the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others note, `delete` is technically an operator and not a function; for our immediate concerns, however, the difference is academic, as the operator's behavior is the same as that of many functions used for their side effects (which is to say, void functions). Both the rule of the language and the conventions of their use are simple.

**Rule**

1. All functions provide a return value; if no `return` statement is reached, this will be `undefined`

**Conventions**

Since we always get a return value, we can take advantage of it to improve our programs. There are two conventions; which one should be used depends on the use case.

1. Return a boolean, signalling success or failure
2. Return some object being operated on

Option 2 is most useful for methods on objects: if our method changes the state of the object and then returns the object, we can bundle several changes into a single line of method calls: `object.change1().change2().change3(newVal);`

Option 1 is most useful when we want to use the success or failure of an operation to determine program flow; maybe we want to throw an exception if the property was not deleted but continue normally if it was. Then we can use `if (delete object.property)` to attempt to delete the property and branch into success/failure cases immediately.

Answer (score 3):

> In that example it looks like delete is used in the manner that a void function

The delete **operator** is not a function, it is an operator. It deals with properties of objects, not their values.

---

Functions are something else, but since you asked:

> Can someone explain to me how JS functions can act with different return values

JavaScript is loosely typed. Functions don't care about the types of values unless they need to, and (most of the time) conversion between types is handled by operators.

If a function needs to are about what it is operating on, then it has to examine the value to see what it is.

For example:

```
function myFunction(myArgument) {
    if (typeof myArgument === "function") {
        return myArgument();
    } else {
        return myArgument;
    }
}
```

A function can return any value it likes.

```
function string_or_number() {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return "1";
    }
}
```

Strongly typed languages care about what type of value a function returns and what type of value is passed into an argument.

Loosely typed ones simply don't. There's nothing special about it from the point of view of someone using the language.

It shunts most of the complexity about having to care about types to the compiler author instead of the user of the compiler (who just has to care that, if a function is designed to do something to a duck, what they pass is sufficiently like a duck to not break the function).

Answer (score 3):

You can check the [Delete operator](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.7) which says:

> If desc.[[Configurable]] is true, then
>
> - Remove the own property with name P from O.
> - Return true.

Note that delete only works for properties of objects. Also a good read:- [JavaScript Delete() Only Affects The Referenced Object Regardless Of Prototype Chain](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2204-javascript-delete-only-affects-the-referenced-object-regardless-of-prototype-chain.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript functions always return ambigious values. One function can return boolean, string, object, array or HTMLElement.

There is no fixed type.

```js
function masterSwitch(input) {
    switch(input) {
       case 0 : return "Hello";
       case 1 : return 0xdead;
       case 2 : return 0.00042;
       case 3 : return document.createElement("DIV");
       case 4 : return true;
       case 5 : return window;
       case 6 : return this;
       case 7 : return null;
       default:window.alert("Please specify input from 0 to 8");
    }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="output"> <SELECT onchange="document.getElementById('output').value = typeof masterSwitch(this.selectedIndex);">
<option>string</option>
<option>int</option>
<option>float</option>
<option>HTMLElement</option>
<option>boolean</option>
<option>window</option>
<option>this</option>
<option>null</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Except `delete` isn't a function.

Comment: Yes, but op asked about return values of functions. not specifically the delete operator.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MDN on the `delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

> Throws in strict mode if the property is an own non-configurable property (returns false in non-strict). Returns true in all other cases.

I can't make it simpler than that. Aside from a small example:

```js
alert(delete window.window)
alert(delete window.foobar)
alert(delete window.alert)
```